# C++ still looks for a .lib file but I can't see why

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, linker

I have a VS 2010 C++ project. 
When I try to compile it, it tells me

Error   1   error LNK1104: File "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\project1\Debug\mysynth.lib" could not be opened.   C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\project1\subproject\LINK    subproject

I have removed all dependencies from Linker->Input->, but it is still looking for the above lib.

Where else could this link be stated?

Comment: see in the Linker-> command line or whatever it is called in VS2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify additional linker options in the configuration dialog. Look under the Linker | Command Line page. Perhaps the errant lib is specified there. In any case you can see there the command line that is passed to the linker and determine whether or not your lib file is there.

The easiest way to work out where they are coming from is to open up the project file in a text editor and search for the errant lib file. If the problem is in the project configuration, this tactic is guaranteed to succeed.

If you have removed everything from your project settings, and you are not passing the errant lib to the linker command line, then the other place where a lib file may be specified is in code. In a `#pragma` statement. It would look like this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mysynth")
```

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I can see lot of dependencides in the Linker->Command line page. How would I remove any from there? This line is greyed out.

Comment: They'll be coming from the other pages on the configuration. Easiest is to search project file in text editor. I added that suggestion to answer.

Comment: I took a look at the very project (subproject.vcxproj) using Notepad, but this .lib was not stated there. Where else could it be?

Comment: Well, now I am stumped. Where else could it really be? Perhaps you could add the project file to the question.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I am sure you are right, and I just need to invest more time to find the dependency. If I do, I will post here. In the meantime thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Look in the properties explorer.  Read the MSBuild documentation for the order that they are read.  This is the most confusing part of going from VS2008 forward.